# scipy.spatial rotation gives different numbers than rotation with pyquaternion or self implementation

Tags: python, scipy, rotation

I compared results of rotating a vector with `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation`, `pyquaternion.Quaternion` and my own implementation.

My own and `pyquaternion` and pretty similar, but `Rotation` is quite different.

```py
import numpy as np
from pyquaternion import Quaternion
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation


def ham(q1, q2):
    a1, b1, c1, d1 = q1
    a2, b2, c2, d2 = q2

    return np.array(
        [
            a1 * a2 - b1 * b2 - c1 * c2 - d1 * d2,
            a1 * b2 + b1 * a2 + c1 * d2 - d1 * c2,
            a1 * c2 - b1 * d2 + c1 * a2 + d1 * b2,
            a1 * d2 + b1 * c2 - c1 * b2 + d1 * a2,
        ]
    )


vector = np.array([-9.86411084, 0.10916063, -0.68953008])
purequat = np.array([0, -9.86411084, 0.10916063, -0.68953008])
# order: w, i, j, k
quat = np.array([-0.54312134, 0.42388916, -0.45617676, 0.5632019])
conj = np.array([1, -1, -1, -1])
quatconj = quat * conj  # hand conjugate
Q = Quaternion(quat)
R = Rotation.from_quat(quat)

print("manual:", ham(quat, ham(purequat, quatconj))[1:])
print("Quaternion:", Q.rotate(vector))
print("Rotation:", R.apply(vector))
print("Rotation inv:", R.inv().apply(vector))
```

```
manual: [-0.14691211  9.88691296 -0.08305227]
Quaternion: [-0.14691852  9.88734378 -0.08305589]
Rotation: [-2.87868815  9.45502779 -0.32195404]
Rotation inv: [-2.33238602  0.16116154 -9.60843655]
```

I think the result of `scipy` is wrong, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Am I misunderstanding something or should I open an issue on the scipy bugtracker?

Comment: It's far more likely that you don't understand it's requirements.  Most of the `scipy` code has been around for years, so if there are bugs it would be in rarely used edge cases, not straightforward ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was of course, very obvious. Given a quaternion `w + xi + yj + zk` then `pyquaternion` treats an array of four numbers as `[w,x,y,z]` while `scipy` as `[x,y,z,w]`.